# Command line arguments in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I want to write a bash script which takes different arguments. It should be used like normal linux console programs:

```
my_bash_script -p 2 -l 5 -t 20
```

So the value 2 should be saved in a variable called pages and the parameter l should be saved in a variable called length and the value 20 should be saved in a variable time.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A variable in what?  Parameters are related to the program you're runnning, not bash in this case.  Does 'myProgramm' take parameters?

Comment: I want to write a program in bash which does this.

Comment: Note that unless you call the script using '.' (`. myProgram -p2 -l 5 -t 20`), the variables you set will only exist in `myProgram`, not the shell from which you call it.

Comment: It really seems to me that his intention is that myProgramm is a bash script. In which case getopts is correct. To avoid this confusion maybe myProgramm should be called my_bash_script. Hey what the heck I'll edit it

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Use the `getopts` builtin:
[here's a tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

```
pages=  length=  time=

while getopts p:l:t: opt; do
  case $opt in
  p)
      pages=$OPTARG
      ;;
  l)
      length=$OPTARG
      ;;
  t)
      time=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

`shift $((OPTIND - 1))` shifts the command line parameters so that you can access possible arguments to your script, i.e. `$1, $2, ...`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 "getopt cannot handle empty arguments strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace. Please forget that it ever existed."

Comment: @Federico your confusing `getopt` and `getopts`... you should read your citation carefully (and please retract the down vote). You can also read [here](http://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/07/16/bash-getopt-versus-getopts/)

Answer (score 13):

Something along the lines of

```
pages=
length=
time=

while test $# -gt 0
do
    case $1 in
        -p)
            pages=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -l)
            length=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -t)
            time=$2
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            echo >&2 "Invalid argument: $1"
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: -1, far better to use getopts

Comment: @StevenMackenzie, ...I'm not sure I can agree. If you look at [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035), the manual-parsing example (of which this is further simplification) does rather a number of things that getopts simply *can't*. Following the practice is thus more flexible.

Comment: @StevenMackenzie, ...we're also in a world where folks have been spoiled by GNUisms such as being able to mix optional and positional arguments (barring the use of `--` to explicitly signal end of the former and beginning of the latter alone). It's easy to do something like `args+=( "$1" )` in a default case with a parser of this kind; with getopts, the cutoff at `OPTIND` is hard-and-fast.

Comment: Bash FAQ 35 (as above) tells me everything I need to know