# Shell how to make some of the script arguments mandatory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I want to run a script which accepts 3 command line options `-o|q|i`. I want to make the `q` and `o` but not `i` so run command **has** to look like:

`script.sh -q <some-text> -o <some-other-text>`

The below code makes none of them mandatory. How can I achieve this?

```
 for arg in "$@"
    do
        case $arg in
            -q) req="$2"
            shift  shift ;;
            -o) out="$2"
            shift  shift ;;
            -i|) ind="$2"
            shift  shift ;;
        esac
    done
```

Comment: @thatotherguy how can I then show a `-help` flag if they are not set?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `getopts`

Comment: You're mixing two different (incompatible) ways of parsing arguments, the `for` loop and the `shift`/`$2` method. Use `getopts` instead -- see [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) and [tzelleke's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036445/command-line-arguments-in-bash/12036574#12036574). More examples (and more complex methods) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash).

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for _options_ to not be _optional._

Comment: @tripleee seems like a semantic point you are making correct? Or are you implying that this is not the way to setup mandatory arguments in shell? I am open to other ideas.

Comment: A common arrangement is to simply require positional arguments without options, like `cp from to` rather than `cp --src=from --dst=to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work by checking that the variables `req` and `out` have some value after the for loop with the below code:

```
  if [[ -z $out  ||  -z $req ]]
  then
    echo "ERROR: -q  and -o are mandatory arguments. See usage: \n";
    exit 1;
  fi
```